# Centos 6: Java Application not Logging to var/log

Tags: java, logging, centos6, tomcat8, logback-groovy

We have a CentOs6 machine which was spun up in OpenStack recently.  A deployment of our companies application consists of building a war file and placing it in /usr/share/tomcat/webapps.  We have deployed it to other CentOs6 machines which were created about a month ago and it logs the application logs to */var/log/myAppName/specifiLogFile.log* just fine.  It's only on the new machines where it's not working (note the older machines assumed to have the same configuration).

**I believe we've narrowed it down to the server itself and not the application.  Other projects, which we build war files for, that are deployed to the new boxes should also log to */var/log/myOtherApp/otherLogFile.log*, but do not.**

I'm wondering if there is anywhere I can look to see why application logs are not being generated in */var/log/...*  What would cause this?

Permissions are 660 for the application's log directory and the correct user has access to read and write.

What I've tried:

Enabling debug in logback and investigating the following logs for issues:  *tomcat/logs/catalina.out*, *tomcat/logs/localhost.2016-06-05.log*, */var/log/messages*

The only other difference was the fact that our older apps were running Java 7, and the new CentOs boxes should be on Java 8.  Even after upgrading to Java 8 the problem persists.

**EDIT:**
Including my logback configuration, but I must say that this configuration works fine on the server that I created about a month ago...  I'm sure that this has to do with some configuration on the new server itself.

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.WARN
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO

scan("30 seconds")

appender("ROLLING", RollingFileAppender) {
  file = "/var/log/myApp/myApp.log"

  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n"
  }

  rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy){
    // Rollover daily
    fileNamePattern = "/var/log/myApp/myApp%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"

    // Delete the archived files older than 10 days
    maxHistory = 10
  }

}

root(DEBUG, ["ROLLING"])
```

Comment: Show us where your logging is set up.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Thank you.  I've added my logback configuration, but mention that this config is working on another machine.  Please let me know if there's anything else I may be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your logging configuration works fine, I would guess, that this is a permission problem:

the directory `/var/log` on your server will surely exist, however make sure that the subdir your app logs to exists (or your application has permission to create that subdirectory).

To test that theory, I would ensure that the directory `/var/log/yourAppName` exists and then run a `sudo chmod 666 /var/log/yourAppName`. After done, restart the application and see if it creates log files into that directory.

If that helps, you might want to revisit that solution however and set the owner of `/var/log/yourAppName` to the user your app runs at and don't allow reading/writing that directory to the world.

Comment: +1 I forgot to mention that permissions were also checked.  Owner and group are correct and permissions are set to 660.  I'll edit my answer to include this.  Thanks!